# Android webview cannot log out of facebook

Tags: android, facebook, webview

On versions of android below Kitkat I cannot log users out of facebook. I log them in using the manual flow as described here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.2
which works flawlessly.
Logout of my application works but they remained logged into Facebook. I have tried everything to log them out including

```
webView.clearHistory();
                webView.clearCache(true);
                android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();
                Log.i("restart","about to restart..");
                Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
                         .getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
                webView.loadUrl(LOCAL_URL);
```

After the activity restarts they click my applications 'login via Facebook button' and Facebook directs them straight back to me stating they are logged in.

Anyone else had this problem?

Comment: what fb logout url do you call while logging out? Do you also send back access token with url?

Comment: I don't call a Facebook logout url. The explanation on the Facebook page above implies that it is not necessary? Also surely if I am successfully clearing cache & cookies then my Facebook session should be removed.

Comment: yes true, `android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookie();` should work